# Three.js BufferGeometry face colors blurring

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm updating the face colors of a `BufferGeometry` in Three.js at the moment, and for some strange reason the colors of the faces are blurring rather than staying contained in their face, producing undesirable results. This is an example of what I mean:

[image]

I would much rather have that triangle be solid rather than blurred. Any insight?

EDIT: So I figured out my issue. When creating a `PlaneBufferGeometry`, the default is to create an *indexed* BufferGeometry, which has effects that can be described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141438/access-to-faces-in-buffergeometry). Since each point is only stored once, and the face color is a gradient of the three vertex colors that make up the face, the color "blurs", as shown in the picture above.

In order to prevent this, but still want to utilize the ease of modifying the position attributes of an indexed BufferGeometry, just modify the position attributes first, then convert your BufferGeometry to a non-indexed BufferGeometry by using

`var geo = igeo.toNonIndexed();`

Where igeo is the initial, indexed BufferGeometry. This will result in clean-cut colors rather than gradients.

Comment: Why don't you show your code so we know what you are doing to generate that result?

Comment: I actually just discovered what I was doing wrong a few minutes ago. I'm going to edit my post in order to help anyone else that runs into this problem.

Comment: Rather than edit your post, please add your findings as an answer, and accept it, so that others performing searches can see this question has been answered at a glance.