# How to perform surface selection in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouse-picking

For my project, I have to select an area (set of triangles) and on mouse hover event, I have to change the color.
As an input, I have a list of area and the set of triangle ID. I use an indexed buffergeometry. I also set a color attribute in order to change the face colors.
[image]

The red box is my target area but when I change all colors of thoses vertex, It has an effect to another neighboor. 
What might be the reason?

**EDITED**

I am now using non indexed buffergeometry. I did not think that vertex coloring is a bit weird like this image below.
[image]

Can I use geometry.groups to separate one surface in order to match it to one material?

**RESOLVED**

The result is due to my mistake because I did not think that colors array is a rgb value per vertex.

Comment: You are sharing vertices. You need to use non-indexed `BufferGeometry` (a.k.a., triangle soup) so each triangle is separate from its neighbors.

Comment: see this answer for an explanation if neccessary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141438/access-to-faces-in-buffergeometry/42167138#42167138

Comment: I have a constraint to use indexed geometry. But can I get my targeted triangles and render it separately?